# Custom Twig Filter from Symfony Bundle not working

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some twig filters that I need on a regular basis bundled together.
But when I install the bundle now the filters are not found.

> Unknown "text2img" filter.

Apparently my service configuration is not accepted because if I put the file twig-tools.yml in the config/packages folder everything works.
But if I understand the symfony documentation correctly the configuration should be detected automatically.v

The symfony version is `5.0.3`

My project structure:

```
├── src
|   ├── Resources
|   |   └── config
|   |       └── twig-tools.yaml
|   ├── Twig
|   |   └── TwigToolsExtension.php
|   └── MyTwigToolsBundle.php
└── composer.json
```

My twig.tools.ymal:

```
services:
    my_twig_tools.twig.extension.text2imgtag:
        class: My\TwigToolsBundle\Twig\TwigToolsExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Please let me know if further information is needed and thank you in advance.

Update (THX to Theva):
I tried

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true
    my_twig_tools.twig.extension.text2imgtag:
        class: My\TwigToolsBundle\Twig\TwigToolsExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

and

```
services:
    my_twig_tools.twig.extension.text2imgtag:
        class: My\TwigToolsBundle\Twig\TwigToolsExtension
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

No one of this worked.

Update (THX to Artamiel)
I added a DependencyInjection to my bundle to load the twig-tools.yaml but nothing changes.

```
namespace My\TwigToolsBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;

class MyTwigToolsExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('twig-tools.yaml');
    }
}
```

Comment: add 2 more parameters to your service autowire: true and autoconfigure: true

Comment: or sometimes public: true

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: The documentation states that a configuration would be load automatically and that's the case with you, the moment you put your configuration in `config/packages`. Do you have `DependencyInjection` folder under your bundle? If not, then read the documentation how to create an `Extension` class, which is used to load custom/bundle configuration on demand.

Comment: Thank you. I added a DependencyInjection for loading my twig-tools.yaml to my bundle but nothing changes.

Comment: All right, I decided to test it myself and it works as expected. There are 2 things I am almost certain you forgot to configure. First - I don't see `YamlFileLoader` namespace imported at the top of the file. Also, you need to override the parent method `getContainerExtension()` in your Bundle file (it's written in the documentation). Do that and it should start working.

Comment: I think I found the main problem, the installation ignores the "type": "symfony-bundle" and does not register the bundle in bundles.php
This should be the case according to the documentation.